# Selecting a random li element - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if there is a way to have JQuery randomly select a `li` inside a `ul` tag.

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

So here is what would happen, lets have a click event so, `$("ul li:last").trigger('click');`  but notice how it has `:last`, how could I specify whether it selects the second, third, or even the fourth `li` based in the tree randomly.

UPDATE:

I notice other suggested using math, what if I have a `ul li` list that is populated by MySQL, I wouldn't know how many `li` there would be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
Math.floor( (Math.random() * $('ul li').length) + 1 );
```

This gives you a number between 1 and the number of `li`, then use the `:nth-child()` selector.

You can learn more about that [here](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: I like this answer better than the other one, because it automatically determines the multiplier by counting the number of li tags.

Comment: Couldnt I just assign a value to what Math.floor equals?

Comment: Don't add 1 since we are dealing with indices.

Comment: @DavidBringa You can, but like Ben Harrison say, this way you can change the number of li and this still works.

Comment: @DavidBiga Yes, any siblings, just use the proper selectors.

Comment: Cool technique! Thanks. Example: `$about` is cached element with children spans: `$('span:nth-child(' + Math.floor((Math.random() * $about.children('span').length) + 1 ) + ')', $about).text()`; this gets the text of a random `span`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a extension function

```
$.fn.random = function()
{
    var ret = $();

    if(this.length > 0)
        ret = ret.add(this[Math.floor((Math.random() * this.length))]);

    return ret;
};
```

This is how you would use it

```
$("ul li").random().trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("ul li:eq(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*4) + ")").trigger('click');
```

You can use `Math.random`.

The random function selects a number between 0 and 1.  Multipling it by 4 and rounding down will give you a number between 0 and 3 everytime.

**Edit**

As suggested in the other answer it is probably a good idea to use the `length` property representing the number of lost items instead of hard coding 4 but do not add 1 since you want to start at 0 since we are dealing with indices.

Comment: This works, but would break as soon as the number of li tags change since the 4 is hard-coded.

Comment: @DavidBiga you don't need to know because you can use JQuery to get the `length` after it is rendered as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution:

```
var list = $('ul li');
list.eq(parseInt(Math.random()*list.length)).trigger('click');
```